# Ideal conditions for Star Trek cultists with nuclear weapons to force the rest of the world to roleplay with them

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-earth, trade

A handful of extremely intelligent and resourceful Star Trek fanatics have, over the course of 2-3 generations assembled an arsenal of nuclear weapons in secret. Upon completion, they plan to broadcast their secret location, weapons capabilities and unveil vast quantities of mineral wealth from asteroids (and rare-earth minerals) to entice the rest of the world to trade with them. This way the cultists may live longer and prosper. But before they begin, one cultist asserted the group, which now number several thousand, show pause until they are as sure as possible they can cultivate the proper conditions for the rest of the world to address them by their Star Trek names and humor their beliefs in Star Trek lore.

Ideally, this would also included being respected as a sovereign nation, but is not a 'must.' There is already precedent for such situations where a group/delegation is treated with considerable 'respect' even though it is not the officially recognized government. How multinational corporations  in failed states tends to deal with operational issues often involves negotiations with de-facto groups in control and rarely apply Westphallian protocols of non-failed states. One such case being Somalia. (Side note: If we're being super-picky, this may fly in the face of international law but it is not uncommon in industry practice).

The point is, for the Star Trek cultists thinking and problem-solving at *warp speed*, that one does not have to undergo a rigorous tick-the-box exercise just to satisfy some arbitrary UN requirements. They hold a veritable sword of Damocles in the form of their nuclear weapons over anyone trying to stop them. Happy or not, we will assume the world order will recognize them -- but the goal is to make the world enjoy the process and role-play with them.

### Question

Would nuclear weapons (stick) and immense mineral wealth (carrot) serve as ideal conditions making the rest of the world role play with them?

**Further clarifications:**

- By role play I just mean addressing the "president" as "Captain Kirk"
  and maybe learning some Vulcan language. They would still be
  conducting real-world commerce.
- Prior to the broadcast, their secrecy is absolute
- Geographic location of their newly carved out territory is not in the
  scope of the question, but let's just say it's a massive space
  station in near-earth orbit so we don't upset any existing
  boundaries. Assume it was cloaked during resource-accumulation stage.
  Otherwise setting up Star Trek HQ in Antarctica would be very
  different than, say, Jerusalem.
- Just looking for a reality-check at the moment, but if something
  jumps out at you in terms of how the Star Trek cultists can improve
  their appeal to the world order, feel free to share

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the plans of characters and how other characters or organizations would respond to your characters plans. Such questions aren't about building a fictional world and are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: You've never actually watched Star Trek, have you?

Comment: The plan is doomed from the start. [Using Nuclear weapons on defenseless civilians is not the Starfleet way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7e7s2KzQls)

Comment: @sphennings A fine point, but I'd counter with saying it's basically planet Earth just with the addition of one extra player on the scene. Ergo, all the legal, geopolitical and societal arithmetic should still be either observable or able to be triangulated.

Comment: @ArashHowaida You're still asking what characters, or organizations in your world will choose to do. Such questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: @sphennings I see the issue, let me attempt a minor tweak, mindful of existing answers. I had the worldbuilding angle in mind during the title, then got a bit jumbled when I reached the question section at the bottom. Should be reconciled somewhat now. Essentially asking about tweaking parameters of my world based on observables from legal, geopolitical, ect from Earth.

Comment: @ArashHowaida You're still not asking about establishing facts of your world but asking about the motivations of characters and organizations within your (already built) world. As a writer you get to decide whether something is sufficiently motivating for your characters or not.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Think about your question with Star Trek characters. Let's say that Cpt Kirk, Janeway and Picard are the leaders of the countries. Kirk would cheat his way out, trick the fans and disarm the nuclear silo with spec ops, Janeway would perhaps enter strict diplomacy in order to not get annihilated and refuse to subdue herself to such protocols, and Picard would follow the game to make them remember about starfleet humanism ideals, removing the nuclear threats and making a new trade partner. As you can see it wildly depends of who's in charge ^^, so that's why it's more story-based.

Comment: This seems an run-of-the-mill "*nuclear blackmail by a non-state actor*" that has been a common trope of action movies since the 1960s. Since the backstory is completely unrealistic, and the demands are completely unrealistic, there's no reason why any solutions need to be realistic. Have your spies smuggle in [Polywater](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Polywater_intoxication) while disabling the launch button, and let the rich fools embarrass themselves.

Answer (score 2):

If we keep our world capitalist as is, their  demande to only be "talk to us in a weird way that stroke our ego and maybe wear funny costum/filter " the nuclear part might be an issue. i mean, they can let know that they are nuclear capable, but they should certainly not, especially when they can just withold the commerce of spacemineral only them have acess too. if you don't negociate in their own term watch those who do get richer. broadly speaking, the carrot will make you friend, the stick might  create tension.

same shtick the other end if they want to reach stathood with broad recognition (and ask for a different tittle), but people might actually  cooperate with them even more on their weird ask. you won't tell to a head of state that his tradition are weird, you hire somebody that will tell you what to say and do to stay in good standing with them